# paho mqtt: Incorrect ouput, when compiling with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, mqtt, paho

I want to set up an mqtt connection. And I want to do it in Python3.

This is a part of the client's code:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received message '" + str(message.payload) + "' on topic '"
          + message.topic + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))

    if message.payload == "Hello":
        print("Received message #1. Do something.")
        # do something

    if message.payload == "World":
        print("Received message #2. Do something else.")
        # do something
```

I'm basically publishing both messages "World" and "Hello" under their given topics to this client but I receive different results based on the python version I use.

This is the output, when I compile with python2: (It's the output I want)

> ```
> pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python Client.py
> Connection returned result: 0
> Received message 'Hello' on topic 'Wulff/test' with QoS 0
> Received message #1. Do something.
> Received message 'World' on topic 'Wulff/topic' with QoS 0
> Received message #2. Do something else.
> ```

This is the output, when I compile with python3:

> ```
> pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 Client.py
> Connection returned result: 0
> Received message 'b'Hello'' on topic 'Wulff/test' with QoS 0
> Received message 'b'World'' on topic 'Wulff/topic' with QoS 0
> Received message 'b'Hello'' on topic 'Wulff/test' with QoS 0
> Received message 'b'World'' on topic 'Wulff/topic' with QoS 0`
> ```

I do not understand why the program won't recognise the message payload here.

What do I have to pay attention to when running a program with different versions of python? I already installed the necessary modules on both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: In Python 3 you have to decode the payload: `message.payload.decode()`. If you are using anything other than the default encoding (UTF-8), you have to give it as an argument to `decode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because with Python 3 the message payload is now considered to be a byte array (this is actually how it should always have been treated)

This can be converted to a String with the following:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode()
    print("Received message '" + payload + "' on topic '"
          + message.topic + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))

    if payload == "Hello":
        print("Received message #1. Do something.")
        # do something

    if payload == "World":
        print("Received message #2. Do something else.")
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. However I find it most peculiar, that this is not mentioned in the documentation of paho-mqtt.

Comment: Also I noticed, that when I lose the `str(message.qos)` in the `print()` statement and just write `+ message.qos` this part of the code will not compile at all. As if it is being skipped. Why does the program not crash in this case, but simply ignore the command?